# React + fetch request

Tags: angularjs, http, reactjs, fetch

I am reading this article [fetch API](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch) and trying to understand how to work with fetch in React. Firstly, could you explain what is **request headers** ?

Than, 
in angular we do something like:

```
$http.get('/someword').success(function(response) {
      console.log('i got the data i requested');
      var variable = response;
      }
```

and than on server side in express I can write:

```
var app = express();
app.get('/thissomeword', function(req, res) {
  console.log('I got a GET request')      
  res.json(someVariableWithData)
})
```

How to do the same with fetch ? And the main question where and when I need to do it ? I understand that i need after i get data to do this.setState({}) for using my data later, but *HOW* is for me huge conundrum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have great facebook documentation:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html
with example that shows what you want

#### headers in request

Sometimes you need header in request to provide access token or content-type (especially in `POST` request)

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  })
})
```

#### Promises instead of callbacks

In your example you pass callbacks (`req` and `res`) to your request, in `fetch` you have [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) so you get response as a paramether of `then` or error message in `catch`.

```
fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    return responseJson.movies;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: [documentation for various request headers](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html)

Comment: Bu what is request headers ? Why they need ?

Comment: As I wrote: "sometimes you need header in request to provide access token or content-type (especially in POST request)", you should read about it

Comment: Are these two example identical ? Just first is with callback and the second one with promises. Am I right ?

Comment: No, first is POST. I see.

Comment: No, all `fetch`es are with promises, first example just have headers and body (as `POST` request often has), second is `GET` request without body and headers (so first example need `then` and `catch` too)

Comment: Ok, I understand here. But what about a place and time where we need to use it in react component?

Answer (score 1):

**Request Headers**

As basic, Request Headers are set by the browsers and the application developers, this is use to tell the web server what the client is sending and what can it accept back in return.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

**Fetch**

Fetch is used to make async network calls. It has a simpler API support based on promises. I'll make your code cleaner with less number of lines.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: and where use it in react component ?

Comment: Use header with fetch. And use fetch inside `componentDidMount` lifecycle method

Comment: I your second reference, everywhere in code write this `fetch('flower.jpg')...`

Comment: What is **flower.jpg**, what can be on this place instead **flower.jpg**.

Comment: I my example it is `someword` ?

Comment: In my example it is `/someword` ?